# Get cell value with a filter on row and column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the value of a cell given two conditions but I am not sure how to achieve it. I tried using `LOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`, `QUERY`, `FILTER`... but got nothing.

I have two sheets.

`Sheet1` looks something like this:

[image: Summary of budgets]

In B1 there's a dropdown where you can select the month: January, February and so on.

Then `Sheet2` looks like this:

[image: Budgets]

It contains the budgets for every month for each category.

I want to show in `Sheet1` a summary of the budgets for the month, for each category, based on the input cell B2. So if you choose January in there, it would show Groceries 500 and Transportation 0.

Hope it is clear, thanks in advance. Here's a sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1puZb3gJz_0oYcQDCDP6MXKoN2vkiyTk-BGXXZB5Gbfc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A:M},SUBSTITUTE("select Col1,Coln label Coln 'Budget'","n",MATCH(B1,Sheet2!1:1,0)),1)
```

---

1. use `{}` to convert the range into a virtual array, such that can query with column number instead of letter
2. use `QUERY` to `select` the category and chosen month columns, and set the `label` to be 'Budget'
3. use `MATCH` to find the column number of the chosen month
4. use `SUBSTITUTE` to put the column number found in 2 into the query string, which is set to Col`n` in advance for replacement

Comment: Works as expected, thanks! Can you explain briefly how this works? I'm not very familiar with Google sheets. Thanks! 

Comment: Added. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise you had found your answer and so I edited your sheet!
Data Validation for a drop-down box and then

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E4, Sheet2!$A$1:$M$16, MATCH($F$1, Sheet2!$A$1:$M$1, 0), FALSE), "")

... to match your Month and Row

Comment: Awesome, this definitely complements the other answer, thank you!